# What happens to my cheese when I overcook it

Tags: cheese

So I wanted to melt some raclette cheese in the oven but was unfamiliar with the settings. So I believe I overcooked it and it turns into this crunchy crumbly dry mixture which is really hard to scrape out. Is this burnt? What happened to it? Is it still safe for consumption?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's overcooked. Maybe not burnt, but it will be grainy, crunchy, or rubbery. Depending on the cheese. I've never eaten that kind of cheese, but you can still eat it, probably, but you probably won't like it.

What happened is you basically bubbled all the moisture out of it and you're left with the fat and protein clumps that are usually uniformly dispersed throughout the cheese.

Comment: ... pretty sure it's the same technique used to make the pure-cheese crackers/crisps, cook till crispy and crunchy.  it's clearly not what was expected, but with a change of context it might not be so bad